# synchronously load html content in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

im using a UIWebView to show html content in my app, the app contains two arrows to navigate between topics just like a RSS reader app, but when the user hits up or down arrow, the next topic doesn't show up until the data come back and the user still able to interact with the UI which is a bit confusing,

My question: how to block the UI when user moves to the next/back topic ? in other words how to make loadHTMLString:baseURL: works as a synchronous calling ? thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can let the load happen asynchronously, but set the web view's userInteractionEnabled property to NO. (then back to YES, on the didFinishLoad callback).

Or you could put up a clear colored view (with userInteractionEnabled set to NO) above the web view that has an activity indicator and button that lets the user cancel the load.

An even better idea would be to place two other web views offscreen and start loading them for page N-1 and N+1.  When the user presses a page arrow, swap frames with the corresponding prefetched web view.

Comment: the last idea seems to be a quite elegant solution, can you please refer me to a good source ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this - https://github.com/gavrix/UISynchedWebView-demo

Comment: I did not need the whole GitHub project, but just the two run-loop calls used did it for me.  Thanks for pointing!

Comment: I wanted UISynchedWebView to work so badly but it fails with UIPageViewController for some reason.  I believe it's because events are still being handled inside CFRunLoopRunInMode(), so UIPageViewControllerDataSource's viewControllerBeforeViewController gets called recursively during the page turn animation.  So if you don't use UIPageViewController, you might be ok.  We desperately need a full example to run UIWebView requests on a separate thread and block until they are finished.

Comment: UPDATE: If you are in a pinch and have a UIPageViewController and still want to use a UISynchedWebView to ensure that a page has loaded before you run javascript, you can run a block on the main thread's event queue.  See my answer for the formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to block the UI. If you do that, there is a very high probability that Apple will reject your app once you send it in for app store submission. Anything that even remotely makes the application feel unresponsive will weigh heavily on you. Instead, create a background thread using GCD or performSelectorInBackground, handle your loading in that, and then once the loading is done, make all of the information available to your UIWebView all at once and alert it to render the display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a pinch and have a UIPageViewController and still want to use a UISynchedWebView to ensure that a page has loaded before you run javascript, you can run a block on the main thread's event queue.  Still has a slight delay while the javascript runs but won't cause recursion in the run loop.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];    // self.webView is a UISynchedWebView

    NSLog(@"url:%@", [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href;"]);       // shows google.com instead of about:blank
});
```